# Find all special characters in a MySQL regexp

Tags: php, regex

I want to match on this regular expression: `\[\[\.\\{0,}(.)?\.\]\]`, so:

a `[` followed by a `[` and a `.`, then a possible number of `\` (0 or more), then a single character and then `.` followed by two `]`'s

This is to find `[[.g.]]` as `g`, '[[.\g.]]' as `g`, but also `[[.\\g.]]` as `g`. I have the following code (for example):

```
preg_match_all( '/\[\[\.(.)?\.\]\]/', "[[.g.]]", $matches );
```

This finds `g` as the match. If I want to ignore escape characters I would change my pattern into `\[\[\.\\{0,}(.)?\.\]\]`, so:

```
preg_match_all( '/\[\[\.\\{0,}(.)?\.\]\]/', "[[.\\\\g.]]", $matches );
```

I would expect `g` back, but I'm getting nothing. The regexp now means: two `[`, following by a `.`, any number of escape characters, then the character we want to find, followed by `.]]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You find back slashes but in the string they are common `"[[.////g.]]"`  ?

Comment: you're right... typo in copying my code from my IDE to stack overflow... doesn't make a difference though, it still doesn't work. Well spotted though :)  I'll edit

Comment: If you aren't already, you might want to use https://regex101.com, makes doing regex a lot easier.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VkPgtT/3

Comment: that's the weird thing @MCMXCII. I use that, and it works there. But when I run this in my PHP7 here it doesn't...

Comment: PHP7: https://repl.it/NtnI

Comment: @AshishRanjan, nailed it! Change the pattern to `/\[\[\.\\\\{0,}(.)?\.\]\]/` (the four backslashes instead of two) and it works, even when matching against `[[.\g.]]` (with a single backslash!!)! I have no clue why though, and that's a dangerous thing...

Comment: @chris, it would fail on the source `[[.\g.]]` even, it can't be the length of the string...

Comment: You need four backslashes because they need to be escaped first for PHP's string (which leaves you with two), and then the regex itself.

Comment: that makes sense @iainn. Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: I meant was that the actual string you were testing with or just a minimal version. Sounds like you have an answer now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably not able to match using your regex because two backslashes mean one (due to escaping), try this (with two but escaped slashes, so 4 in total):

```
$re = '/\[\[\.\\\\{0,}(.)?\.\]\]/m';
$str = '[[.g.]]
[[.\\g.]]
[[.\\\\g.]]
[[.\\\\\\\\g.]]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Live demo [here](https://repl.it/NtnI)